# Got an error reading communication packets error on MySQL 8.0 and memory issues

Tags: mysql, sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I updated MySQL 5.6 to 8.0 on GCP and started getting a lot of error of **(Got an error reading communication packets)**.

I tried to update the parameter **max_allowed_packet** from **94994432** to **409362432**,
and the parameter **wait_timeout** to **14400**.

Also, I updated the **memory** from **3GB** to **50GB**, and the memory its always at limit!

Any idea about this memory consumption, and all the logs errors?

Comment: Please post TEXT of the last 100 lines of your Error Log for quick review. Thanks

Comment: [MY-010914] [Server] Aborted Conecction [329150] to db: 'db_name' user: 'root' host: 'cloudsqlproxy-IP' (Got an error reading communication packets).

All the lines look the same. @WilsonHauck

Comment: Could you post a sample?

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout%; and SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%aborted%'; for analysis and possible suggestions.

Comment: If you could post last 100 lines of errorlog, we would get an idea of the frequency.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem. After updating MySQL from 5.7.41 to 8.0.32 (Debian 11), I noticed a lot of error messages in the MySQL error log (about 10 messages per min):

```
[MY-010914] [Server] Got an error reading communication packets
[MY-010914] [Server] Got an error reading communication packets
[MY-010914] [Server] Got an error reading communication packets
```

I'm tired of tweaking a lot of settings, timeouts, etc. Nothing helps. Then I downgraded my MySQL to 5.7.41 and no more errors.